# How to Implement the function, which returnes index of tuple in the list with maximum sum of elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need an index of the element with the max sum inside of it, but what I done is only found the maximun inside the tuple in a listm instead of fining the index. Could you please help.

```
def max_sum_index(tuples):  
   
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    maxi = 0
  
    # traversal in the lists 
    for x in tuples: 
        sum = 0 
        # traversal in tuples in list 
        for y in x: 
            sum+= y      
        maxi = max(sum, maxi)  
          
    return maxi

print(max_sum_index([(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)]))
#72
```

Answer (score 2):

to keep track of indices you may want to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i,x in enumerate(tuples):
```

then to keep track of index you need a variable for the highest sum and the index of that sum:

```
maxi = 0
max_val = 0
```

If you find an element that has a sum higher than `max_val` then that becomes the new max, along with it's index

```
    if sum > max_val:
        max_val = sum
        maxi = i
```

So you'd have something like:

```
def max_sum_index(tuples):  
   
    maxi = 0
    max_val = 0
  
    # traversal in the lists 
    for i,x in enumerate(tuples): 
        sum = 0 
        # traversal in tuples in list 
        for y in x: 
            sum+= y
        if sum > max_val:
            max_val = sum
            maxi = i 
          
    return maxi

print(max_sum_index([(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = [(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)]

index = sample.index(max(sample, key=sum))
print(index)
```

**Output:** `1`

Comment: Or just `key=sum`. I don't see the benefit of `lambda x:sum(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

uses a tuple with sum as first element to get maximum and include original tuple
index is the second element of the tuple, original tuple is the third element:

```
print(max((sum(x),i,x) for i,x in enumerate([(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)])))
print('index: ', max((sum(x),i,x) for i,x in enumerate([(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)]))[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list `max` function over your tuple.

```py
max_index = max(enumerate([(10, 20), (40, 32), (30, 25)]), 
                key=lambda x: x[1][0]+x[1][1])[0]

print(max_index) #outputs 1 in this case
```